# Reinstalling Picasa 3

Tags: picasa

How do I reinstall Picasa 3 which was inadvertently deleted. Also how to recover albums organized in Picasa 3?

Comment: Have you tried simply reinstalling it? It should just pick up the settings left behind

Answer (score 3):

You can check your filesystem for Picasa.ini files (just activate show hidden items in Windows). if these Picasa-files still are there, you should be able just to reinstall Picasa and it should start with all the settings you made earlier. Picasa itself doesn´t remove the .ini files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following set of instructions (found [here](http://www.karinvandenberg.nl/node/86)):

> Before (re)install on old system, copy/backup the c:/documents and settings//local settings/application data/Picasa2 folder
>
> After (re)install on new system:
>
> 2. Install Picasa (yes it's Picasa 3 atm but it still creates a Picasa 2 folder)
> 3. Start Picasa and let it scan as little as possible (you don't have to wait for it to finish scanning), turn Picasa off
> 4. Go to c:/documents and settings//local settings/application data/ and rename Picasa2 to something like Picasa2_newinstall
> 5. Copy the old Picasa2 folder to c:/documents and settings//local settings/application data/
> 6. Start Picasa